# Twitter REST API v1.1 - searching by date?

Tags: python, twitter, python-module

Is there a way to use Twitter's API 1.1 to conduct a search for all posts with a particular query on a particular day or for the last week?

Should any python module that complies with the API be able to do this (I've been using twython), or is there any specific module that people can recommend for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, **yes**.

For example:

```
#Import the required modules
from twython import Twython
import json
import csv

#Set the path for the output file
path = r'C:\Users\etc\file.txt'

#Setting the OAuth
Consumer_Key = 'XXX';
Consumer_Secret = 'XXX';
Access_Token = 'XXX';
Access_Token_Secret = 'XXX';

#Connection established with Twitter API v1.1
twitter = Twython(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Secret, Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret);

#Twitter is queried
response = twitter.search(q='%40annoys_parrot', since = '2014-02-04', until = '2014-02-05');

#Results are printed
print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys = True, indent = 2))

#Results are saved to txt file
file = open(path, 'w')
file.write((json.dumps(response, sort_keys = True, indent = 2))) 
file.close()
```

Then, you only need to parse the results. You can find more information about this [here](http://www.alessandroscocciapappagallo.com/programming/query-twitter-api-v1-1-python/).